# Submit button does not work unless I refresh the page form_for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, form-for

I have an app that has a problem model and when I go to create a record the submit button does nothing. No errors given it just simply doesnt execute, unless I refresh the page and attempt add it again. The same happens when I go to update a record.

Here is my controller

```
class ProblemsController < ApplicationController
 include Concerns::Votes
def index
 @problems = Problem.all
end

def show
 @problem = find_problem
end

def new
 @problem = Problem.new
end

def edit
 @problem = find_problem
end

def create
 @problem = current_user.problems.new(problem_params)
 @problem.save
 redirect_to @problem
end

def update
 @problem = find_problem
  if @problem.update_attributes(problem_params)
    redirect_to @problem
  else
    redirect_to @problem
  end
end

private

def find_problem
 @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
end

def problem_params
params.require(:problem).permit(:name, :description, :url)
end 
end
```

Here is my _form.html.erb partial that I am rendering on new.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<%= form_for @problem do |f| %>
<label>Name</label>
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name your problem!" %>
</div>
 <div class="large-8 columns">
<%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: "Link to any supporting material" %>
 </div>
 <div class="large-12 columns">
 <%= f.text_area :description %>
 </div>
 <div class="large-12 columns">
 <%= f.submit "Create" %>
 </div>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

I have resources :problems in my routes.

Here for good measure is my show.html.erb as well.

```
<%= div_for @problem do %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_problem_path(@problem) %>
<h2><%= @problem.name %> (<%= @problem.cached_votes_score %>)</h2>
<a =href"<%= @problem.url %>"><%= @problem.url %></a>
<p><%= @problem.description %><p>
By <%= @problem.user.name %></br>
<a class="button"<%= link_to 'Up', {:controller => 'problems', :action => 'up_vote'}, {:method => :post } %></a>
<a class="button"<%= link_to 'Down', {:controller => 'problems', :action => 'down_vote'}, {:method => :post } %></a>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_problem_path(@problem) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', problem_path %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <% @problems.each do |problem| %>
    <h1><small><%= problem.cached_votes_score %></small> <%= link_to problem.name, problem %></h1>
 <% end %>
 </div>
 <%= link_to 'New Problem', new_problem_path %>
</div>
```

I really cant understand why it works if i refresh the page but otherwise it doesnt work at all.

Comment: where is `form_for` ?

Comment: @RSB Apologies I pasted wrong code. I have amended above.

Comment: Instead of <%= f.submit "create" %> 
do <%= f.submit :submit %>
try this ..

Comment: You may need to change the place you put form_for and end tag. Just because it's not placed right, so it need us to refresh the page before handling function!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, the submit button is actually not nested under the form tag. Try changing your view code to this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <%= form_for @problem do |f| %>
      <label>Name</label>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name your problem!" %>
      <div class="large-8 columns">
        <%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: "Link to any supporting material" %>
      </div>
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </div>
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <%= f.submit "Create" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is under `form_tag`

Comment: Check the source of the rendered HTML page. The <input type="submit"> tag is not under the <form> tag there.

Comment: Much appreciated both of you. Bit of a dim moment here for me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I was banging my head against the wall over this forever, when I realized the issue was missing the closing carat of a div tag (`</div`). Oddly enough, on page refresh, firefox was magically fixing the markup for me, though on initial page load, the HTML was broken and it was so hard to notice that one missing character! I diddnt even notice until I read this answer and triple checked that the submit button was inside the form, and the bracket highlighter plugin for Sublime 3 told me it wasnt!!

Comment: Same, I had an extra `</div>` and had no idea that this would cause my button to render outside my form

Comment: Had the same problem, also found extra `</div>`.

Comment: Same here, an extra `</div>`. I wish I had an editor that showed these better. But hard trying to see div and Rails logic `do` and `end` mixed together. Mainly posted to say still a problem and a fix another year later and with Rails 6.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue

**Before**

```
<%= simple_form_for(:schedule_list, url: schedulelists_create_with_block_path, :html => { novalidate: false}) do |f| %> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'pull-right' %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
</div>
```

**After**

```
<%= simple_form_for(:schedule_list, url: schedulelists_create_with_block_path, :html => { novalidate: false}) do |f| %> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.button :submit, class: 'pull-right' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: should be `f.submit 'button-text', class: 'pull-right'`